# Office JS: Find the last row with data in on an Excel sheet and copy that information onto another sheet?

Tags: excel, office-js

I have previously used VBA to find the last row that contains data on an Excel sheet and the used this to copy specific cells on that sheet across to another Excel sheet, however we have now begun using excel online so I was wondering if there was any way to replicate this in office JS?

An example of the VBA code that I was using before for reference is below, is there any way for this to be easily converted into office JS?

```
Sub FormCreate()
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form").Range("A1") = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form").Range("B4") = Sheets("Data").Range("B" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form").Range("F1") = Sheets("Data").Range("C" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form").Range("E3") = Sheets("Data").Range("D" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form").Range("F4") = Sheets("Data").Range("E" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form").Range("D2") = Sheets("Data").Range("F" & (ActiveCell.Row))
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Use the [Worksheet.getUsedRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#getUsedRange_valuesOnly_) method to get the entire range that has data. Then on the Range object that is returned, call the [Range.getLastRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#getLastRow__) method. Then read the [Range.values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#values) property of the Range object that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You need get the current sheet first, the used range, and after that, get the last row.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

    //get the current sheet
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();

    //get the current used range and lastRow
    let myUsedRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();
    let lastRow = myUsedRange.getRowCount();
    
    //print
    console.log(lastRow);
}
```